# Am I still allowed to edit link-only answers in the queue, or should I always delete them?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I failed a [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15223227) when I tried to improve a link-only answer with a summary from the link.

It was a link-only answer, but the [link in the post](http://www.websnube.com/how-to-install-configure-setup-cakephp-in-xampp-server-on-windows-7-8/) *did* provide a valid answer to the question. It was a blog post with detailed instructions.

I clicked to edit the post to include a summary of the information in the post, but was told I failed the audit and that the answer was deleted as "offensive, or spam".

From my reading it seems like the consensus is that *"link-only answers" should be deleted*, as per:

- [Your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)
- [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/172778)

That is, except if they're old answers that are accepted.

Should I delete all link-only answers in the review queue, or can I continue trying to improve link-only answers (and thus ignore the audit)?

Comment: It's just another unfair audit, why nuked as spam?, maybe OP post multiple answer with link to that site, hence mod's had information that you as reviewer did not have, carry on  with what you are doing, if you get reviewed ban for this, I guess mods will lift your ban.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238647/dont-use-spam-post-as-audits-in-the-low-quality-review-queue?s=3|2.0737

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Since you slightly changed your question, I will expand my comment in an answer*

## Your audit

The post was probably flagged as spam and then confirmed as spam by a moderator (also OP of the answer is nuked, so mortal users can only guess why). There where no indications looking merely at the post that it is spam, not even searching [metasmoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=websnube&username=&why=&site=&feedback=&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search)* can that site be seen as a frequent spam target.

**Conclusion:** The audit was not fair, you could not possibile have enough information to delete it as spam and your intention was to edit

## Am I still allowed to edit link-only answers in the queue?

Yes you are allowed to edit **all** link-only answer and it is appreciated by the community.

Your difficulty is to **create a reasonable answer**, avoiding to create an answer that just quote another page while being careful to not "put words in OP's mouth". This extra effort of editing link only answer is normally only worth it if question is good and the link-only answer is appreciated (upvoted, accepted).

Considering this maybe it's wise to exit the queue and have a look at the question, other answers etc, before editing (this way you will also not fall in this trap again)

Remember that if you edit an answer in the LQP queue it will automatically exit the queue, so do not edit if your not sure that you can create a nice Q/A pair, there is always the skip button.

**Final conclusion:** Carry on with your great effort to improve SO and don't worry about this mishap it's fairly common since the audit system is not perfect.

<sup>*Website of a community project, searching for spam</sup>

Answer (score -2):

Are you asking if link-only answers should be deleted as spam instead of edited? I think a better question is this: if someone chooses to edit a post flagged as spam/offensive, should that fail an audit?

I would say not necessarily. Offensive content can be removed and spam can be made into reasonable uses of the website. Editing therefore should not be assumed by the automated system to be an invalid action to a spam/offensive post.

Comment: I'm still confused as to why it was considered "spam or offensive".

Comment: @GustavBertram Considering it was deleted by a mod, not the community (the amount of downvotes indicates this), it's likely that either the user is posting from a wellknown spam IP range, or this link has been seen many times before from this user.

Comment: "spam can be made into reasonable uses of the website" I'm skeptical on this bit, but agree on the rest.

Comment: Removing spam/abusive text before a question/answer is deleted can affect the automated spam/abuse detection (users will not flag it as spam/abusive). See [Should Spam posts be edited?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030).